# Unwanted excel save prompt when opening with access vba

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an access VBA program that opens an excel file in order to retrieve some data.

```
Private Function getSampleDescription() As Boolean
' Assign the Excel Object
If gfcHandleErrors Then On Error GoTo errorExit:

getSampleDescription = True
Dim excelapp As Object
Set excelapp = CreateObject("excel.application")

' Assign the workbook
Dim wb As Object
Set wb = excelapp.Workbooks.Open(fileName:=fileName, ReadOnly:=True, Password:=sampleFilePassword)

'Assign the sheet
Dim sh As Object
Set sh = wb.worksheets("Sample Description")
```

It had been working fine but recently (not sure why), I get an excel prompt asking Save, Don't Save or Cancel.
[image: Excel Save Prompt]

This happens immediately after the Workbooks.Open statement.  If I choose Save I get a prompt to save the excel table to Copy of ExcelFilename. Once I save the code then proceeds normally.   If I choose Don't Save the code just proceeds normally.  If I choose Cancel the prompt reappears; choosing Cancel a second time aborts the code.

Any idea what is provoking this?  Could it be password protection on my workbook or worksheets.  How can I make it stop!

Access and Excel 2010 versions operating on Windows 7.

Thanks for any help ...

Comment: Does the workbook have any macros which fire when it's opened?  You could try adding `excelapp.DisplayAlerts = False` before opening the workbook.

Comment: does the excel sheet have any code that is trying to save the workbook?

Comment: Tim - No, there are macros but none which are triggered by opening the workbook.

Comment: EngineersMnky - no save code

Comment: Tim - DisplayAlerts = false seems to have solved the problem.  Thank you

Comment: tim has already given you on how to avoid the prompt. However I am curious as to why are you getting that prompt. Excel will never prompt you to save a file the moment you open it..

Comment: Siddarth - it is a mystery to me.  If I had more time I would investigate it.  Unfortunately, I must move on with my project.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the following to the very top of your VBA code.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

This essentially stops any alert windows from popping up and disrupting your code. Please note: if you don't want to save the excel file after you've retrieved data from it, this should work fine, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was asked 3 years ago, but seems the answer has not been added. Excel prompts to save the document because your code executes an open procedure and re-evaluates the file to a read only, which is effectively a change in the document itself therefore requiring a save procedure.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ChangeFileAccess XlFileAccess.xlReadOnly
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

As previously stated by other users the above code will suppress the prompt box but do not forget to revert it back to True after the particular code has executed as you could prevent other errors from displaying.

Comment: I just tried opening a workbook in read-only mode (using the code from the question) and it didn't decide that my desire to open it read-only meant it needed to save it (which would completely defeat the purpose of opening it as read-only anyway).

Comment: The code only prevents the box coming up i will edit to show the full code i use. You will need to enable content first before the script is executed.

Comment: `ChangeFileAccess` just changes the file to be in read-only mode - it doesn't require the workbook to be saved in order to do that.  (It's not setting the file to be read-only, it's just changing the version open in memory to be in read-only mode so that changes can't be saved.)

Comment: The code evaluates like this, Open File (Read-Write), ChangeFileAccess(Read-Only) if you were to open the file manually as a read only the code is null and void as you said. But as the user above stated he ran the excel file from Access which is totally different.

Comment: I have tried the code from Access too - Excel continues to open the file in `[Read-only]` mode (due to the `ReadOnly:=True` parameter in the `Open` statement), and doesn't need to save the file as soon as it opens in order to do so.